# Where can we buy shares of ASICMiner

Tags: asic, investing, finance

> ASICminer did decide to keep the hardware and mine. They're selling
>   shares with intent to payout the dividends from whatever profit is
>   made.

Okay, so we got three players. ASICminer. Avalon. And butterfly labs. Obviously ASICMiner is the one most convenient. We don't need to do anything. We just pay. And get results.

So where can I buy ASICminer share?

Also how do they pay dividend?

So we own a share. Then we login to their site, and then we insert our bitcoin address? Or what?

Where is their website?

Comment: Generally the term "share" in finance refers to a share of equity of a company or other entity.   So what is the name of the entity that you are inquiring about?  [Of course, your response will be "ASICMINER, duuuuhhhhh!", to which the response to that will be, .. and in which legal jurisdiction is said ASICMINER company registered, and which type of entity (e.g., LLC, corporation, etc.) are they registered as?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disclaimer: At the time of this writing, I am a shareholder with ASICMiner.

Also be aware that the Bitcoin stock market is, like Bitcoin, very immature and not regulated. The risks involved are far greater than for a traditional stock market.

Like @Steven Roose just wrote, you can buy Pass-Through (PT) shares through two separate stock exchanges, [BTC-TC](https://btct.co/security/ASICMINER-PT) and Bitfunder. I personally prefer the former due to its easier interface, but either works.

However, know that these are PT shares only. A PT means that you buy shares with someone who holds real shares with ASICMiner. In practice, it is much the same, but both PTs will charge a 0.5% fee from your revenues, and you don't get voting rights, so keep that in mind.

For 'real' shares, ASICMiner do not sell those directly. They were sold initially at a now defunct stock exchange (GLBSE) which turned into a bit of a disaster and after that, friedcat, the person in charge of ASICMiner, decided he did not want his stocks traded on any exchange for fear of similar accidents.

That said, there are a lot of people that hold 'real' shares, and these are sometimes put on auction over on Bitcointalk.org (check https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=73.0). In case you wint one of these auctions, the seller will transfer the sold amount by sending a message to friedcat with your email address and your Bitcoin address for dividends. I suggest using one of the escrow service providers on that forum to ensure the transfer goes smoothly and safely. Several escrow providers will do this for free, but it is customary to tip a few bitcents at least for their service.

Dividends for PT shares are paid to your exhange account and directly held shares are paid directly from friedcat to your Bitcoin address on file.

Beyond that, ASICMiner does not have a web page per se, but they keep everyone informed several times a week here:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=99497.0

Like I said, be very careful about investing in Bitcoins and cryptocurrency stocks. There is no regulation, no recourse, and seldom any personally identifiable information.

And again, I am a current ASICMiner share holder, so keep that in mind as you read this.

EDIT: I've posted a more comprehensive and up-to-date answer here:
http://coin.furuknap.net/how-to-buy-asicminer-shares/

.b

Comment: So no body knows who owns asicminer? HOw do we know they're not a ponzy? Do they have asic?

Comment: I've explained the ownership in more detail in the article I added. In short, ASICMiner is a virtual identity representing a portion of shares in the Bitfountain company, which is incorporated in China.

Comment: I trust bitcoin and asicminer. But who the hell is bitfunder? What about if bitfunder run with my money?

Comment: Bitfunder is just a stock exchange; they do not have your money beyond the time you take to move it there and buy the shares. The shares themselves, in the case of Bitfunder, is in your hands and tracked by DeaDTerra, reported to him every day. If Bitfunder goes down, DeaDTerra can simply transfer the PT to another exchange or exchange the PT shares for regular shares for you.

Answer (score 4):

[Originally](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=99497.0), ASICMiner sold share on [GLBSE](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/GLBSE), a Bitcoin stock exchange that has already closed it's business.

Currently, you can buy their shares both on [BitFunder](https://bitfunder.com/asset/G.ASICMINER-PT) and [BTC Trading Corp](https://btct.co/security/ASICMINER-PT).

Comment: While the answer above is much better, this one actually answer the questions. +1 for both. I selected this.

Comment: For those who don't know, bitfunder is crowd founder website!

Answer (score 0):

PT shares can also be found [through](https://www.havelockinvestments.com/fund.php?symbol=ASICM) Havelock Investments, based out of Canada.

Answer (score 0):

[Cex.io](https://cex.io/r/0/jumbo987/0/) is a site where you can buy GHS and you start to mine btc or you can sell GHS for btc, it's some kind of market, but when you keep GHS you are mining.